# Android Intent Action "ACTION_CALL" - Correct way of getting back to own application after call?

Tags: android

I got one question regarding the intent action "ACTION_CALL".

What is the correct way of getting back to the own application/activity after the user ends the call?

The only way that came to my mind uses a PhoneStateListener in a background services that waits for the CALL_STATE_IDLE event starting up the application again. But I am not quite sure if that is the correct/intended way of using the intent.

I am looking forward reading your answers.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is the only way you can do this.